# Syntactic Sugar Struct Reference in Swift?

Tags: swift

In `c++`, one can introduce an *alias reference* as follows:

```
StructType & alias = lengthyExpresionThatEvaluatesToStuctType;
alias.anAttribute = value; // modify "anAttribute" on the original struct
```

Is there a similar syntactic sugar for manipulating a (value typed) struct in *Swift*?

**Update 1:** For example: Let say the struct is contained in a dictionary of kind [String:StructType], and that I like to modify several attributes in the the struct myDict["hello"]. I could make a temporary copy of that entry. Modify the copy, and then copy the temporary struct back to the dictionary, as follows:

```
var temp = myDict["hello"]!
temp.anAttribute = 1
temp.anotherAttribute = "hej"
myDict["hello"] = temp
```

However, if my function has several exit points I would have to write `myDict["hello"] = temp` before each exit point, and it would therefore be more convinient if I could just introduce and alias (reference)  for `myDict["hello"]` , as follows:

```
var &  alias = myDict["hello"]! // how to do this in swift ???
alias.anAttribute = 1
alias.anotherAttribute = "hej"
```

**Update 2:**  Before down- or close- voting this question: Please look at  *Building Better Apps with Value Types in swift* (from WWWDC15)!! *Value type* is  an important feature of  *Swift*! As you may know,  *Swift* has borrowed several features from `C++`, and *value types* are maybe the most important feature of `C++` (when `C++` is compared to *Java* and such languages). When it comes to *value types*, `C++` has some *syntactic sugar*, and my questions is: Does `Swift` have a similar *sugar* hidden in its language?. I am sure `Swift` *will* have, eventually...  Please, do not close-vote this question if you do not understand it!

I have just read *Deitel's book on Swift*. While I'am not an expert (yet) I am not completely novel. I am trying to use *Swift* as efficient as possible!

Comment: Can you expand your explanation on exactly what that C++ code equates to?  What's the `&` there? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @nhgrif: He's modifying `lengthyExpresionThatEvaluatesToStuctType` [sic] by calling it `alias` in future lines, the way a reference type would work.

Comment: Is it necessary to have two different variables referencing the same struct within the same scope?  This question really needs to be quite more specific on what exactly is trying to be accomplished in what context.  I understand that the asker may not be a Swift expert, but it's important to learn how to do things the Swift way rather than simply try doing things the C++ way with Swift syntax.  So be clear about what is trying to be accomplished with perhaps specific examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift doesn't allow reference semantics to value types generally speaking, except when used as function parameters declared `inout`. You can pass a reference to the struct to a function that works on an inout version (I believe, *citation needed*, that this is implemented as a copy-write, not as a memory reference). You can also capture variables in nested functions for similar semantics. In both cases you can return early from the mutating function, while still guaranteeing appropriate assignment. Here is a sample playground that I ran in Xcode 6.3.2 and Xcode 7-beta1:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Foundation

var str = "Hello, playground"

struct Foo {
    var value: Int
}

var d = ["nine": Foo(value: 9), "ten": Foo(value: 10)]

func doStuff(key: String) {

    let myNewValue = Int(arc4random())

    func doMutation(inout temp: Foo) {
        temp.value = myNewValue
    }

    if d[key] != nil {
        doMutation(&d[key]!)
    }
}

doStuff("nine")
d // d["nine"] has changed... unless you're really lucky

// alternate approach without using inout
func doStuff2(key: String) {

    if var temp = d[key] {

        func updateValues() {
            temp.value = Int(arc4random())
        }

        updateValues()
        d[key] = temp
    }
}

doStuff2("ten")
d // d["ten"] has changed
```

You don't have to make the `doMutation` function nested in your outer function, I just did that to demonstrate the you can capture values like `myNewValue` from the surrounding function, which might make implementation easier. `updateValues`, however, must be nested because it captures `temp`.

Despite the fact that this works, based on your sample code, I think that using a class here (possibly a final class if you are concerned about performance) is really more idiomatic imperative-flavored Swift.

---

You can, if you really want to, get a raw pointer using the standard library function `withUnsafeMutablePointer`. You can probably also chuck the value into an inner class that only has a single member. There are also functional-flavored approaches that might mitigate the early-return issue.

Comment: Thanks, (+1),  I have to think about this before I mark it as "the answer"!

Comment: Sure. It was an interesting question to research and think about. I guess I should have lead with, "No, there is no such syntactic sugar." However it's hard to prove a negative :)